# Where to put constraint classes in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, naming-conventions, ruby-on-rails-3.2, convention-over-configur

Just curious about the best practices for Rails in where I put a custom constraints class that's used as a constraint in config/routes.rb. Seems like `Rails.root/lib` is where all user classes go. Is that appropriate for this? Should I be creating a directory inside for constraints? 2 empty directories exist there now, `assets` and `tasks`. Are there conventions for this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`lib/` would be the appropriate place. If you want to make it cleaner, put it in `lib/constraint/authenticated.rb` and define your constraints like so

```
module Constraint
  class Authenticated
    def matches?(request)
      # stuff
    end
  end
end
```

and in your `routes.rb`

```
constraints Constraint::Authenticated.new do
  match 'account' => 'account#index'
end
```

Comment: Didn't know you could specify constraints that way. Didn't see that in the Rails Guide, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.

Comment: I have basically the same exact set up - except I get a `NameError: uninitialized constant Constraint` error. When I remove the module, and just reference `MyConstraint.new` (with no namespace), it works. Why does wrapping this in a module throw such an error? I really want that namespace ><

Answer (score 12):

This is strange that the guide says nothing about that path, but **lib/constraints** is even listed in the API ([ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scoping](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-constraints)):

> You are able to move this logic out into a class if it is too complex for routes. This class must have a `matches?` method defined on it which either returns true if the user should be given access to that route, or false if the user should not.
>
> ```
> class Iphone
>   def self.matches?(request)
>     request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] =~ /iPhone/
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> An expected place for this code would be ***lib/constraints***.

Comment: While the API suggests `lib/constraints`, I think `app/constraints` is a more appropriate place because the latter is loaded automatically but the former is not. This is just _my_ practice, though.

Comment: Whether it's loaded automatically in development shouldn't matter. I make the decision depending on whether that particular class is domain-specific, following this blog post: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/02/07/what-code-goes-in-the-lib-directory/